# How to change Icon of Dynamically added value from database into google autocomplete dropdown?

Tags: autocomplete, google-places-api

I am appending some address which is stored in database when an user searched for particular address using google autocomplete place. Autocomplete places show me suggestions for that address with default icon. I want to display new suggestions with the default icon and address from database with a different icon. How can I do this?

can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: More detail, please.  Are you using `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` in the Google Places API Javascript Library (like in this sample: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) or something else?

Comment: yes i am using google.maps.places.Autocomplete. I am giving you details.

I am requesting cab using phonenumber and location and destination. For Location and Destination i am using google autocomplete. now i want something like when user come to send next request he/she enter phone number, when user try to find location using autocomplete i want to add previously requested locations with autocomplete suggestions and destination respectively. That i have done. But i want to change icon of that previous request data which is right now default icon of google autocomplete.